# How can you scale a large image in responsive design with no height?

Tags: image, css, responsive-design, media

For my website this is what I am using for the image with regards to responsive design:

```
 .logo {
 max-width: 100%;
 display: block;
 height: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 }
```

The image scales properly width wise but the image's height is too big.  In these kinds of situations what can one do to make the image scale properly? If I remove height auto and assign 70px the image looks good when viewed in full version but as you begin to shrink the size of the browser the image looks like it's going inwards.

HOw can i fix this?

Comment: Are you assigning that class to an <img> tag? If so, it scales proportionally just fine for me. If the browser window shrinks, it shrinks the width AND the height of the image, proportionally. 

Perhaps include some screenshots of the problem?

Comment: Yes i am using the img tag.  I'll see if i can post screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
{
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for this wrapp a div around img and apply the height you want and overflow hide it

```
.imgwrapp {width:100%;height:70px;overflow:hidden;float:left}
```

Answer (score 0):

So given the css you have there, the ratio of width to height of the image is what's giving you problems. If you don't like the height of the image when the browser is wide, then you should probably get a different image/crop it. When you set the height to 70px what you're doing is forcing the image into a box that it doesn't fit in, so the image will look funny as it's being scaled weird.

But alas there is another option. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/E66TM/) is a jsfiddle that shows only the amount of the image that fits within my first n pixels (in your case 70) so that way it will kind of slide out of view. Check the css here :

```
.header {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.everythingelse {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  But that doesn't work well with what i have in mind.